# RoleManager class (WriteToLog method) moved or replaced?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm working on a WCF Service that should be hosted in Windows Azure environment, so I'd like to use `RoleManager.WriteToLog` method to log events. I found many articles, describing usage of this class, usually dated 2008 or 2009.

I'm **unable to find** that `RoleManager` class (not even `Microsoft.ServiceHosting.ServiceRuntime` namespace in Add Reference window). All I see is `RoleEnvironment`. Has this class been **moved or replaced**, or am I **missing something**? I'm using **Visual Studio 2010 with Windows Azure Tools**.

Cheers
Matthias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The namespace was deprecated as part of the [November release](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2009/11/23/november-2009-release-of-the-windows-azure-tools-and-sdk.aspx) of the Azure SDK. Use the [Azure Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee843890.aspx).